# Tomcat common location for common jars of webapplications

Tags: java, tomcat, dependencies

**strong text**I have multiple webapplication which use, some common dependencies, like 
mongo connector 
google guava 
jodatime

I thought of taking them out from webapp/WEB-INF/lib and put in to some common-lib directory, this way I can reduce the size of the war file and the deployed directory.

I try to override the common class loader jar file location by editing the **catalina.properties** found at tomcat-/conf

common.loader=${catalina.base}/lib,${catalina.base}/lib/*.jar,${catalina.home}/lib,${catalina.home}/lib/*.jar,${catalina.home}/lib/ext/*.jar,**${catalina.base}/common-lib/***.jar

I make sure all the common dependencies and there transitive dependencies are copied to the common-lib

Now I'm getting ClassNotFoundException, any clue on the root cause for this issue

One more question, can I expect any kind of memory usage reduction by moving the jars to a common lib

Comment: replace `.jar` with `*.jar`. ups, you **have** the asterix chars. what particular class is `NotFound`? maybe the JAR's you've moved to common loader depend on som JARs that where left behind?

Comment: Hi I put *.jar in my original post, seems stackoverflow bold option have issue with * in middle :), any way for the next question you asked

Comment: did u try putting the common jars in lib folder of tomcat?

Comment: I dont think that their would be any reduction by moving jars as each web application is still using the same number of jars that were needed before. Though if unneccessary jars removed than yes their is memory reduction.

Comment: Hi I put *.jar in my original post, seems stackoverflow bold option have issue with * in middle :), any way for the next question you asked ClassNotFoundException comes from a class that is not inside the common-lib, its from a class which is inside webapp

Comment: @Jhanvi ya I did try it also failed,

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to restore you tomcat to the initial install condition without changes, and then add your jars (mongo, guava, etc) to the `/lib` directory under the tomcat installation directory, as described [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html).

Also, it would be helpful if you post which class is missing.